# How to order by after rollup and not split grouping?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rollup

I use rollup and i want to order by best year (by profit not in alphabetical order) and not split groups of years.
Each year order by best product (by profit not in alphabetical order) and not split etc.

I want something like this:

[image: table1]

But i have only this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS abc;
CREATE TABLE abc(year  text,
                      country text, product text, profit integer);

  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2016', 'USA', 'Phone', 3000);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2016', 'USA', 'TV', 1000);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2016', 'UK', 'TV', 2000);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2016', 'UK', 'Phone', 1000);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2015', 'USA', 'TV', 1500);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2015', 'USA', 'Phone', 1000);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2015', 'UK', 'Phone', 900);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2015', 'UK', 'TV', 600);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2014', 'USA', 'Phone', 1500);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2014', 'USA', 'TV', 1000);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2014', 'UK', 'Phone', 1500);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2014', 'UK', 'TV', 2000);

with data as
(
SELECT year, country, product, profit from abc
  )
 select l.year as year, l.country as country, l.product as product,
  sum(l.profit) as profit
 from data l 
group by rollup(year, country, product)
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN year IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, year
```

When i order by sum(l.profit) it split years.

Comment: Remove the `order by`.  I think it will put the results in the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add more to the order by clause:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS abc;
CREATE TABLE abc(year  text,
                  country text, product text, profit integer);

  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2016', 'USA', 'Phone', 3000);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2016', 'USA', 'TV', 1000);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2016', 'UK', 'TV', 2000);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2016', 'UK', 'Phone', 1000);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2015', 'USA', 'TV', 1500);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2015', 'USA', 'Phone', 1000);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2015', 'UK', 'Phone', 900);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2015', 'UK', 'TV', 600);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2014', 'USA', 'Phone', 1500);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2014', 'USA', 'TV', 1000);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2014', 'UK', 'Phone', 1500);
  INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('2014', 'UK', 'TV', 2000);

with data as
(
SELECT year, country, product, profit from abc
  )
 select l.year as year, l.country as country, l.product as product,
  sum(l.profit) as profit
 from data l 
group by rollup(year, country, product)
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN year IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
year,
case when product is NULL THEN 1 else 0 end,
profit desc
```